# Run the bash script every time when command lines are executed

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, execute-command

I am a new Ubuntu/Linux user, I would like to ask a question as my title above.

For example, I have a bash file `./script`, I would like to make it run automatically when I type any command line. Once I execute command line `pwd` then the `./script` will be executed. Once I type the next command line `ls -la` then the `./script` will be executed again.

Comment: may we ask : what kind of action you are intending to do on *each and every* command typed? and should it be only for those typed interactively? or also for any command in a script? and what about commands typed over ssh ? etc. This could be a [XYProblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/235138)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to set `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable. From `man bash`:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND
              If set, the value is executed as a command prior to
              issuing each primary prompt.
```

For example, this will write current date into `/tmp/PC` every time a command is executed:

```
 $ PROMPT_COMMAND="date > /tmp/PC"
```

Comment: Yep, I got it.. pretty cool solution. ( upvoted)

Comment: This is wrong. The command `echo $(date)` will be run at declaration time, so will always show (save) the same time.

Comment: @heemayl: of course you're right, I fixed it

Comment: @lộcphan If one of these answers solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @heemayl: Why? ...

Comment: Oh, i missed the edit. Ok now.

Comment: Only problem with this is that it runs before the prompt is shown rather than after a command is run. Normally it makes no difference but it does mean that it'll be run whenever you open a terminal even if you don't run a command.

Answer (score 11):

You are looking for `PROMPT_COMMAND` environment variable, the value of this variable will be executed as command, after each command given in the terminal is executed, just before showing the next prompt.

For example, set it as:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='/path/to/script'
```

Make the script, `/path/to/script`, executable first.

Now the script will be run after each command.

Just to note, if you don't want the variable to be exported i.e. make it a shell variable instead of a environment one, drop `export`:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='/path/to/script'
```

From `man bash`:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND 
If set, the value is executed as a command prior to issuing each primary prompt.
```

Comment: I got it, thank you so much for your help :) ( upvoted btw )

Comment: Why are you using `export`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk `export` will make the variable `PROMPT_COMMAND` an environment variable i.e. the variable will be available to all child processes (e.g. subshells) of the current shell. If you just want to confine it within current shell session only (shell variable), remove `export`.

Comment: @heemayl: IMO `export` is not a good practice here - `PROMPT_COMMAND` should only be set in an interactive shell startup file and should not be visible in environment